# Show that $\ c_X(p,q) \le d_X(p,q)$, for $ p, q \in X$

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, functional-inequalities

**Update**

I'm trying to show the **Corollary**, but I have stuck...That is:

> For any complex space $X$, we have:
>   $$\begin{align} (1).\ c_X(p,q) &\le d_X(p,q),\ \text{for}\ p, q \in X \\
> (2).\  c_X(p,q)&\le \delta_X(p,q) \le d_X(p,q),\ \text{for}\ p, q \in X\end{align}$$
>
> with
>
> - $c_X$: the Carathéodory pseudo - distance:
>     $$c_X=\sup_{f\in \text{Hol}(X,\Delta)} \{\rho \left(f(p),f(q)\right)  \}$$
> - $d_X$: the Kobayashi pseudo - distance:
>     $$d_X=\inf_{\alpha\in \Omega_{x,y}}\{ \sum_{i=1}^{k}\rho(0,a_i) \},\ \forall a_i \in \Delta=\{z \in \Bbb C:|z|<1\}$$

[image: 1]

> - $\rho$: Bergman - Poincaré distance: 
>     $$\rho_\Delta=\log \left(\dfrac{1+|z|}{1-|z|}\right),\ \forall z \in \Delta$$
> - $\delta_X$: is a pseudo - distance on $X$.

I think we can apply **Proposition**:

## [image: 2]

I can show that $c_\Delta \le d_\Delta $ But How to prove that $c_X \le d_X $?

=================================

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I do not understand what $\delta_X$ is, but the inequality 1 follows from the Schwartz lemma in the unit disk: Every homomorphic self-map contracts (i.e. does not increase) the Poincare distance.

Comment: I'm sorry but I think you want to say *holomorphic*, it's a typo, maybe. You mean http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz%27_lemma ? Can you show it (the inequality $(1)$), plz! If you use the definition of $c_X,\ d_X$ or the **Schwarz lemma**. Thanks!

Comment: OMG, since your idea I have a solution, hihi. Now I write it: Applying **Schwarz–Pick theorem** we have: $$c_\Delta(p,q) \le \rho_\Delta(p,q)$$ On the other hand, we have $$\rho_\Delta(p,q) = d_\Delta(p,q) $$ Hence, we're done. But we consider $c_X,\ d_X$ it means "on $X$"?

Answer (score 1):

Let $x, y\in X$. Then, by the definition of $d_C$,  for every $\epsilon>0$ we can find $g\in Hol(X, \Delta)$ such that
$$
d_C(x,y)-\epsilon< \rho(g(x), g(y))\le d_C(x,y).  
$$
By definition of $d_X$, for every $\epsilon>0$ we can also find a "holomorphic chain"
$$
f_i: \Delta\to X, f_i(p_i)=x_i, i=1,...,n, f_1(p_0)=x, f_n(p_n)=x_n=y,  
$$
such that
$$
d_X(x,y)\le \sum_{i=1}^n \rho(p_{i-1}, p_i) < d_X(x,y)+\epsilon. 
$$
Set $h_i=g\circ f_i$. Then, by Schwartz lemma, for every $i$, 
$$
\rho(g(x_{i-1}), g(x_i))= \rho(h_i(p_{i-1}), h(p_i))\le \rho(p_{i-1}, p_i)
$$
and in view of the triangle inequalities for the metric $\rho$, 
$$
\rho(g(x), g(y))\le \sum_{i=1}^n \rho(g(x_{i-1}), g(x_i)) \le \sum_{i=1}^n \rho(p_{i-1}, p_i). 
$$
Thus,
$$
d_C(x,y)-\epsilon< \rho(g(x), g(y))< d_X(x,y)+\epsilon. 
$$
Since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary,
$$
d_C(x,y)\le d_X(x,y)
$$
as required. qed

Comment: I'm sorry when I say that I don't understand  $$d_X(x,y)= \inf K(x,y)$$ where $$K(x,y):= \{\rho(p,q): g\in Hol(\Delta, X), p\in g^{-1}(x), q\in g^{-1}(y)\}$$? $\delta_X$ (Your question...),  my pro only say that, it means $$c_X(p,q) \le \delta_X(p,q) \le d_X(p,q),\ \text{for}\ p, q \in X$$?? I updated, can we use it?Thanks!

Comment: @ **studiosus**: R u sure $$K(x,y)=L_\alpha ???$$

Comment: What I wrote needs to be rewritten using chains, I just have no time right now.